# ASP.Net listview layout behaving oddly

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to use a ListView in an ASP.Net page and failing to get the results I was expecting. My page looks like this:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label class="subHeading">Contacts</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" id="lvwContacts">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div class="tableWrapper">
                                <div class="tableScroll">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th><label>Full Name</label></th>
                                            <th><label>Job Title</label></th>
                                            <th><label>Direct Line</label></th>
                                            <th><label>Mobile Phone</label></th>
                                            <th><label>Email</label></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                        ... etc
```

but when I look at the output the table is not appearing inside the divs:

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
    <div class="tableScroll"></div>
</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><label class="subHeading">Contacts</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th><label>Full Name</label></th>
    <th><label>Job Title</label></th>
    <th><label>Direct Line</label></th>
    <th><label>Mobile Phone</label></th>
    <th><label>Email</label></th>
    </tr>
    ... etc
```

I've tried putting the divs around the whole listview with much the same result. What on earth is going on here? Have I done something stupid or do ListViews really behave like this?

Thanks

John

Comment: try using a `<asp:PlaceHolder />` instead of `<tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>`. Your ItemTemplate has a `<tr>` already in it so you are making invalid markup with nested `<tr><tr>`. A `<tr>` should only have a `<td>` or `<th>` as a child.

Comment: No, that's how ListView works. The <tr id="itemPlaceHolder ... is telling .net where to place the rows. I haven't posted enough of the output for you to see, but the extra <tr> is not in the output. If you leave it out you get a compiler error.

Comment: John what I meant was to create  `<asp:PlaceHolder id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />` and replace it with your `<tr>` placeholder.... not remove the placeholder altogether. You are creating invalid markup, and the browser will sometimes correct this by altering your markup. Just try placing a `<a>` inside another `<a>` like this: `<a><a></a></a>` and see the rendered output. It happens in your example too... do you have a `<tbody>` in your LayoutTemplate? No, but its in the rendered output because the browser corrected this invalid markup. I am just saying make your markup valid.

Comment: Ok, well, I gave it a go and it made no difference. However, if you look at Microsoft's own documentation for the ListView class you'll see they tell you to use <tr ...>. As I said, it's just a placeholder for the ItemTemplate and gets replaced at runtime.

Comment: Ok understood. Where is `<label class="subHeading">Contacts</label>` in relation to your LayoutTemplate? I see it in your rendered output but not in the LayoutTemplate. Could you include this in your first snippet?

Comment: Ok, done. As you see, it appears above the divs. There's no way that the divs should be appearing in front of it.

Comment: oh... try wrapping the `<div class="tableWrapper">` in a `<td>` in your Layout Template since it's parent is a `<tr>`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure you have valid HTML markup. Currently one of your `<tr>`'s has a `<div>` as a child, not a `<td>` or `<th>`.

See this demo:

```css
/* style used to illustrate problem */
.tableWrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<label>Invalid markup</label>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="subHeading">Contacts</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <!-- Invalid. child is a div not a td or th -->
    <div class="tableWrapper">
      <div class="tableScroll">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th><label>Full Name</label></th>
            <th><label>Job Title</label></th>
            <th><label>Direct Line</label></th>
            <th><label>Mobile Phone</label></th>
            <th><label>Email</label></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>

<label>Valid markup</label>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label class="subHeading">Contacts</label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <!-- This is required! -->
      <div class="tableWrapper">
      <div class="tableScroll">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th><label>Full Name</label></th>
            <th><label>Job Title</label></th>
            <th><label>Direct Line</label></th>
            <th><label>Mobile Phone</label></th>
            <th><label>Email</label></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Inspect the rendered output of both tables... you will see what happens when the markup is not valid (what you are experiencing) the browser removes the `<div>` from the table. The second table has correct markup so it renders as-is

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to be something I'd done.