# Table ends panel-body early, causing format errors

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to fit a GridView (or a ListView, I've tried both) into the panel-body of a div panel.  However, whenever the GridView appears, it closes out the panel-body early and causes formatting issues.

I've tried GridView, ListView, rearranging the elements of my panel, and I've trimmed a lot of stuff back to get it down to just the GridView.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvOuter" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="placeHolder" DataKeyNames="PkUser" OnItemCommand="lvOuter_ItemCommand" OnSorting="lvOuter_Sorting" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvOuter_SelectedIndexChanging" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lvOuter_PagePropertiesChanging">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="placeHolder" runat="server" style="width: 100%"></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr style="align-content: center;">
                    <td class="listViewFooterText" style="color: white; text-align: center">
                        <uc:listviewpager runat="server" id="ucOuterListViewPager" listviewcontrolid="lvOuter" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user x1" style="text-align: left;" />
                    &nbsp;
                                <b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbEmployeeTitle" runat="server" Style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;" Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeName") %>'></asp:Label></b>
                    &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbUnapprovedTitle" runat="server" CssClass="badge badge-blue" Text='<%# Eval("TotUnapproved") %>'></asp:Label>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvInner" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("IndividualTracking") %>' AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="PkTrainingRequest" OnRowCommand="gvInner_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40%" HeaderText="Title">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="kbTitle" runat="server" CssClass="gridViewRowText" CommandName="Populate" ToolTip="Go to Training Request" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="Length">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="kbLength" runat="server" CssClass="gridViewRowText" CommandName="Populate" ToolTip="Go to Training Request" Text='<%#Eval("Length") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30%" HeaderText="Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="kbDate" runat="server" CssClass="gridViewRowText" CommandName="Populate" ToolTip="Go to Training Request" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="Approve">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnQuickApprove" runat="server" Text="Quick Approve" CssClass="btn btn-success" CommandName="Approve" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDrillDown" Text='<%#Eval("Subordinates") %>' CommandName="DrillDown" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("VisibleSubordinates") %>' />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnViewTraining" Text="View All Training" CommandName="ViewTraining" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Expected result: panels, each with a header and footer, and a gridview (when it populates) in the body.

Actual result: the panels work fine until the gridview populates.  When that happens, the panel-body ends before the gridview, and the panel-footer attaches to the top of the next panel.[image]

Comment: I think you have invalid HTML markup. Your `<div class="panel panel-default">` in your ItemTemplate should be inside a `<td>` and it is not. Only `<td>` and `<th>` are allow to be immediate children of `<tr>`'s. I just answered a similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280040/asp-net-listview-layout-behaving-oddly/55285945#55285945). See if the answer helps you

Answer (score 1):

You made a `tr` the `placeHolder`. So it generates this, which is incorrect html

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
    <tbody>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            xxx
        </div>
```

So if you want to use a correct table, make the LayoutTemplate like this

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvOuter" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="placeHolder">
    <LayoutTemplate>

        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="placeHolder" runat="server"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="panel panel-default">

        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Which generates

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-default">

                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This still places everything in a single table cell. If you want a cell per ItemTemplate you need to put `<tr><td>` in it.